# Not all updates can be installed in software updater

Tags: 20.04, updates, update-manager

In ubuntu 20.04 version, when I open software updater, I see "Not all updates can be installed". A screenshot is attached. Why is it happening and What to do to solve this? [It may be mentioned that no problem occurs if I run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` in terminal, it runs successfully].

I wanna know another thing. Is this update from software updater and update in terminal [`sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade`] same?

[image: Update_problem_screenshot]

Comment: Are you using NVIDIA graphics driver? I got this message recently and it was because old versions of some NVIDIA packages were not uninstalled during previous upgrades. If you click "Partial Upgrade", the tool will show you what packages it wants to remove and what to install. There should be maybe two or three old NVIDIA packages to remove and a bunch of new ones to install. If this is the case, it should be OK to proceed. If not, try to find all installed versions of NVIDIA packages in Synaptic and remove all except the last version. Then a normal upgrade should succeed.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I know very little about a PC. How to find which graphics driver I am using?

Comment: But yes, I searched for NVIDIA and found NVIDIA X server settings. So maybe I am using NVIDIA graphic driver. If I am right (that I'm using NVIDIA driver), then should I proceed to partial upgrade?
I apologize again to say that I don't have any idea about these things...

Comment: If you proceed to partial upgrade, it should show you the list of packages it is about to install/remove. If there will be NVIDIA packages on the list, as I wrote in previous comment, you may proceed. Otherwise, you will still have a chance to cancel the operation.

Comment: Thanks for your help. When I clicked partial upgrade, it showed me 27 to install, 1 to remove and 69 to upgrade. That was to remove was something regarding nvidia, so maybe this is the procedure you were saying. Thanks again for your time and help!